# How do I find the SubscriptionDefinitionID for each of my keywords in Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I added two new keywords today -  a JOIN and Opt Out keyword. I need to find the SubscriptionDefinitionID that matches each of these new keywords. Does anyone know the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while since this question was posted but I found a way to identify the keyword IDs that doesn't involve using SQL queries.
You can navigate to the MobileConnect Administration page, click in to a shortcode and you should be able to see all the related keywords below.
If you pull up the html for the page on your web inspector you can see the ID for each keyword in the HTML for the page. Hopefully this speeds up documenting these keyword IDs in the future.[image: see green boxes for keyword IDs]

Answer (score 2):

On top of those 2 solid answers, there are another 2 ways, which could be used and they will complete the list of possible ways.

- Do a REST API call with GET method to the `https://[your_domain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/attributeSets/name:MobileConnect%20Subscriptions` endpoint to retrieve all mobile subscriptions and then filter them by the mobile number and subscription status -

  [image]

  here is a [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000315190&type=1) explaining that.
- Very last option considers that you have already sent at least one SMS to this keyword and you can easily get it by querying [_SMSMessageTracking Data View](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) and get the value from the "KeywordID" field.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here is what I learned, in case it is helpful to anyone else.

To find my subscriptiondefinitionID for my new Join keyword, I picked a Contact - went to ALL Contacts, and in the Membership tab, I added myself to the subscription for that keyword. Then I made a SQL activity to query the SMSSubscriptionLog and only looked for that one contact's subscriber key. This then pushed the data into my DE and I could tell which subscriptiondefinitionID related to my keyword based on the OptIn Date timestamp.

If there is another faster way to do this I am all ears, but this at least is a temporary solution. Thanks all.